# Save Login state, logical error with SharedPreferences and passing a Bundle

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, bundle

I am developing my first networking application and have a small problem which I am unable to find a solution for.

On my startscreen, which is my main activity, there is the option to login. If you login, my login class passes data per intent to my main activity so I can update my UI. This is my main acitivity :

```
    // Just to make sure Loginstatus is false on first run
    loginstatus = false;
   //Get saved data from SharedPreferences
    loginstatus = PreferenceData.getUserLoggedInStatus(this);
    Log.d("Loginstatus",""+loginstatus);

    if (extras != null) {

            login = extras.getString("loginy");
            idt = extras.getString("id");
            name = extras.getString("name");
            vorname = extras.getString("vorname");
            email = extras.getString("login");
            zsm = vorname + " " + name;

    }

    else {

        // Take saved Data instead the Bundle Data form first Login
        idt = PreferenceData.getUSERID(this);
        name = PreferenceData.getNachname(this);
        vorname  = PreferenceData.getVorname(this);
        email = PreferenceData.getLoggedInEmailUser(this);

    }
```

Obviously extra is NULL on Startup. If login was successful, my login class passes Data and my main activity is called again, so extras is NOT NULL and I can update my UI with that information.In addition, I save my Data in SharedPrefernces if login was true.

The Problem is, I want to save my login state after completley closing my app. So i reopen my App and I want to use my SharedPrefernces data, but somehow extras is still NOT NULL and I cant find a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle login. Hope this is helpfully.

**Login Activity**

Keep one shared preferences value to check login status which default value set to false;

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
            initializeDatabase();
            sharedpreferences.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).apply();
            sharedpreferences.edit().putBoolean("attendance", false).apply();
            sharedpreferences.edit().putBoolean("loginStatus", false).apply();
        }
        loginCheck();
    }
```

inside `loginCheck()` check method redirect to menu activity based on login status.

```
public void loginCheck(){
        if(sharedpreferences.getBoolean("loginStatus", true)){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            this.finish();
        }
    }
```

In case of User haven't log previously, after authenticate user successfully add needed data in to shared preference and change login status shared preference value to true so above explained redirect will happen.

```
if (message.equals("Login successful")) {
                        String employeeId = responseBody.getString("employee_id");
                        int userId = responseBody.getInt("user_id");
                        String employeeName = responseBody.getString("employee_name");

                        SharedPreferencesReference.get().edit().putString("employee_id", employeeId).apply();
                        SharedPreferencesReference.get().edit().putInt("user_id", userId).apply();
                        SharedPreferencesReference.get().edit().putString("employee_name", employeeName).apply();
                        SharedPreferencesReference.get().edit().putBoolean("loginStatus", true).apply();

                        Toasty.success(ActivityWeakReference.get(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityWeakReference.get(), MainMenuActivity.class);
                        ActivityWeakReference.get().startActivity(i);
                        ActivityWeakReference.get().finish();

                    }
```

**Menu Activity**

In menu activity you should have a logout button which allow users to logout by changing shared preference login status value. In My case I had it as a Menu Item.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                sharedpreferences.edit().putBoolean("loginStatus", false).apply();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```